# There's no pom.xml in my spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I'm trying to write a spring boot project by watching a YouTube tutorial. When I added the frameworks shown in the video, I found no pom.xml file in my project folder.

I tried creating it manually but it doesn't load Maven.

Answer (score 1):

use spring initializer,
we dont know about the youtube tutorial

https://start.spring.io/

with spring initializer the maven pom can be autoegenrated according to your needed dependencies in a really easy way

Answer (score 1):

You can use ready-made options for initializing (creating) projects. One of the options is the Spring Initializr. Here you can select Maven or Gradle (top left) and add the necessary dependencies (top right). The result can be downloaded as an archive and run from IDEA.

[image: What does the initializer look like in the browser]

Another option would be to use the initializer inside the IDEA itself.

`File -> New -> Project`

[image: initialization via IDEA]

Here you can also select the necessary options for the project.

If you are just starting to learn Spring, you can ignore the Group and Artifact options on the first projects. You will find out what they are for later.

Be sure to check if you have the maven plugin enabled in IDEA itself:

[image: maven plugin]

`Settings -> Plugins ->` scroll down to Build Tools

Good luck!